Is there an official source to know for each Ubuntu release what was the systemd version applied?
Is there an official resource where is available a complete list of all the Ubuntu releases but including the respective version of systemd applied for each one? I found this systemd/NEWS page where appears each systemd version but I want to know for each Ubuntu release what was the systemd version applied.

You could look up package details of what is included in the release ISO by looking in the manifest  ... ie. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop (https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) contains systemd 255.4-1ubuntu8  for amd64   (most packages are the same version for all architectures; but there are exceptions, esp. with ported architectures)   This will show package details anyway; but similar detail can be quickly obtained for current releases via CLI enquiry; ie rmadison systemd

This question is similar to: How to know default software version for all Ubuntu software for a specific Ubuntu version?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@guiverc thanks for the suggested approach, it should be the correct answer because is accomplished through the web as an official resource. The command approach is useful too because all is shown together and being specific for a software, in this case for systemd.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/ is the web based way that provides the same results as my CLI approach (though CLI provides ESM releases that won't appear on web searches).  Looking up old manifests files allows you to also get package details from EOL releases that have been dropped and thus don't show on any other method

Sure, apt will tell you about the current release.
Example from 23.10:
$ apt-cache madison systemd
   systemd | 253.5-1ubuntu6.1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 Packages
   systemd | 253.5-1ubuntu6 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 Packages

The rmadison script  (included in the devscripts package) will tell you about all open releases:
$ rmadison systemd
 systemd | 204-5ubuntu20      | trusty            | source
 systemd | 204-5ubuntu20.31   | trusty-security   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 systemd | 204-5ubuntu20.31   | trusty-updates    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 systemd | 229-4ubuntu4       | xenial            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 systemd | 229-4ubuntu21.27   | xenial-security   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 systemd | 229-4ubuntu21.31   | xenial-updates    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 systemd | 237-3ubuntu10      | bionic            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 systemd | 237-3ubuntu10.57   | bionic-security   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 systemd | 237-3ubuntu10.57   | bionic-updates    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 systemd | 245.4-4ubuntu3     | focal             | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 245.4-4ubuntu3.20  | focal-security    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 245.4-4ubuntu3.23  | focal-updates     | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 249.11-0ubuntu3    | jammy             | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 249.11-0ubuntu3.7  | jammy-security    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 | jammy-updates     | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 253.5-1ubuntu6     | mantic            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 253.5-1ubuntu6.1   | mantic-updates    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 255.4-1ubuntu8     | noble             | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 255.4-1ubuntu8     | oracular          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 255.4-1ubuntu8.1   | noble-updates     | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 systemd | 256-1ubuntu1       | oracular-proposed | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x


Note: Some "open" releases are past the End of Standard Support. We don't, for example, provide community support for Trusty, Xenial, nor Bionic anymore. They remain open for Pro customers.

